# Encountering java.net.SocketException During Flutter Project Run in Debug Mode

Tags: java, android, flutter, windows, gradle

II'm working on a Flutter project, and I've encountered a persistent issue where I receive a `java.net.SocketException` error when attempting to run the project in debug mode. The error suggests a network connection failure, which I'm unsure how to resolve. Below is the complete error message I receive:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond       
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:330)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:355)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:808)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:484)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:160)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1510)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1425)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:589)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:187)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect0(HttpURLConnection.java:2922)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2831)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1927)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

Steps Taken:

Checked and confirmed my internet connection is stable.
Temporarily disabled firewall and antivirus software.
Updated Gradle to version 8.7 and confirmed the distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties.
Executed flutter clean and flutter pub get.
Attempted to bypass the Gradle Wrapper by directly using Gradle.
Considered system reinstallation but decided to seek help first.

Environment:

```
Flutter version: 3.19.4,
Dart version: 3.3.2
Gradle version: 8.7
Operating System: Windows 11
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or does anyone have insights on resolving this SocketException? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For forgot to insert the error message. Please edit your question and include the full error message including stack trace as text and format it as code. `SocketException` means a network connection failed.

Comment: just updated the question

Comment: Seems to me like a common network or server problem when Gradle tries to download gradle wrapper. The same problem was mentioned here some years ago: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/74619 If it is not a server problem some firewall/middleware in your network my block the connection.